# How can I show code error in VSCode by hovering over it

Tags: visual-studio-code

Today, I was watching a video tutorial. The tutor did a minor mistake in his code and while he was trying to find out what the mistake was, he hoverd over the code and exactly at the place, where his error was, VSCode popped up with an Error message like this:

[image]

Does any one know how can I activate this in my VSCode? Do I need to install an extension?

Comment: See also "[VSCode shows class definition on hover. How to make it stop?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75648313/6309)"

Answer (score 8):

The setting is called "Editor > Hover: Enabled". You can search for it in the VSCode settings and make sure the box is checked to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

this should be a built in feature but may need enabling it.. 
more info at 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/249839/vs2017-1571-no-values-on-hover.html