# VSCode shows class definition on hover. How to make it stop?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode does this annoying thing where it shows the definition of a class or function when my mouse hovers over it.

I'd like to see the errors when relevant, instead of the implementation code of my class/function.

In this image, I'm hovering over `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator`

[image: In this image, I'm hovering over GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to see the errors when relevant, instead of the implementation code of my class/function

VScode 1.77 (March 2023) should help, with [issue 73120](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73120) "For long hovers, errors appear all the way at the bottom and require scrolling".

It is resolved in [PR 166560](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/166560) (from  [Avatar
Ariel Davis](https://github.com/azdavis)) and available with [VSCode insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

It puts marker hovers on top of all other hover kinds, and shifts down all hover kinds that used to be ahead of marker hovers by 1.
An effect of this is that diagnostic messages are now on top when hovering.

Before:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6496454/202396229-143a5d48-55fb-4a7f-971c-c053b331d96e.png]

After:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6496454/202396221-9e06661a-5904-457d-aaf8-2abcd6691671.png]

Other examples:

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6496454/206282780-fb410c19-7cb1-474e-a800-093f52421fc0.png]

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6496454/206282782-7569b298-06ff-441f-a6a5-1128f93836a0.png]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the docs for a particular piece of code overlaps with the error message.

There are some ways you can get around this to see the error message.

1. In your image, if you scroll down to the end of the docs you can see the error message.
2. Also scrolling down you can see a `View Problem (<some-command>)`, where `<some-command>` usually is `Alt + F8`. If you click it, it will open a pop-up for navigation through all the problems and errors in your code.
3. You can open your panel, go to the tab "PROBLEMS" and see the problems/errors in your code.

[For items 1. and 2. refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2Ft2.png)

[For item 3 refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCFj5.png)

If you want to get rif off the hover action, you can go to "Settings", search for `hover` in the search area and [disable it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuXwB.png)